# How do I find my python/django source code on Mac (Yosemite)

Tags: python, django, macos

Quite embarrassing, but I can't find the python source code on my Mac (Yosemite).  Going through the Django tutorial and stuck on the step below.

Now create a directory called admin inside templates, and copy the template admin/base_site.html from within the default Django admin template directory in the source code of Django itself (django/contrib/admin/templates) into that directory.

```
import sys
>>> sys.path = sys.path[1:]
>>> import django
>>> print(django.__path__)
['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/lib/python3.4/site-packages/django']
```

I don't see a "Frameworks" folder in my Library folder (although I can 'cd' my way there in the terminal.  The finder doesn't reveal anything when searching.  I read somewhere it might by in a "System" folder, but I can't find that either.  I also might be able to complete this step without accessing the folder?

I also believe I've found two different locations using terminal?

```
$ ls /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/
3.4

$cd /System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions
Versions $ ls
2.3 2.5 2.6 2.7 Current
```

Answer (score 4):

Without virtualenv:  **path/to/your/python/X.X/site-packages/django** . In my case  **/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django**

using virtualenv:  **/Users/ME/.virtualenvs/my_virtual_env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django**

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

In your finder window if you show the **Devices** on the left sidebar you can search within your **Macintosh HD** for the **Library** folder which should contain your **Frameworks** folder. At least that's what worked for me.